# Reopen sub task if parent issue is not in closed status-(JIRA Workflows)

Tags: workflow, jira, jira-plugin, jql

I need to configure the sub task workflow to enable reopen transition if the parent issue is not in closed status.I have added the "reopen" transition to the sub task workflow and tried to find a way to apply built-in  conditions in jira to check whether the parent issue is closed or not and ended up with no result.

I have tried "condition based on JQL queries" and "Condition on subtasks"

is there any other way or plugin to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend that you install the [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin for JIRA if you are running a self-hosted instance.

Then on the conditions page for transition:

1. Click `Add Condition`
2. Select `Script Condition` and click `Add`
3. Click `Simple scripted condition`
4. Enter the Condition to be:

   ```
   issue.parentObject && !issue.parentObject.status.name.equalsIgnoreCase("Closed")
   ```
5. Click `Add`.

The condition will ensure that the issue has a parent and that its parent isn't in the `Closed` status.